# VoiceXML(VXML) to HTML conversion in Java

Tags: javascript, java, android, ivr, vxml

1. I am looking for a standard way to convert VoiceXML(VXML) to HTML in Java.
2. Do we have any Transcoder available to convert the above.

If anyone tried/known about the above, Please share your comments/thoughts

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are looking for, Visual-IVR http://www.visual-ivr.com/technical/ may be the type of thing you are looking for. There may be other solutions out there, but I am unaware of any free and/or open-source software/libraries that would assist with this.

VXML to HTML adaptation would really depend on what you want to do -- they're really not the same thing, though they could be considered to fit in the same basic layer in a MVC framework, and share a fair amount of basic web architecture and standards. If you want to pretty-print VXML on for a VXML developer to read, that's one thing. If you want to come up with a web form (or series of web forms) that ask the same questions as an IVR application executing that VXML would ask, that's another, and could get down into hairy details of grammars and recognition engines, and translating that to clickable options.